# How can you access the css rules of a document.stylesheet element if its cssRules property is null?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to scrape all the css rules on an html page. This question has been asked [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679507/getting-all-css-used-in-html-file) but I have not found a solution for sites like stackoverflow. If you paste in the console:

```
for (var p in document.styleSheets) {
  console.log(document.styleSheets[p])
}
```

you will notice that some of the `cssRules` are null (at least in chrome).

```
CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null, cssRules: null, rules: null, type: "text/css", href: "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=284b207e2cf7"…}
CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null, cssRules: CSSRuleList, rules: CSSRuleList, type: "text/css", href: null…}
CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null, cssRules: CSSRuleList, rules: CSSRuleList, type: "text/css", href: "http://static.adzerk.net/Extensions/adFeedback.css"…}
CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null, cssRules: null, rules: null, type: "text/css", href: "http://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/styles/jobs.min.css?v=8228069a845b"…}3
```

Simply navigating to http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=284b207e2cf7 will produce the minified css, however.

Is there any way of programatically obtaining the css rules of a site when the `document.styleSheets[].cssRules` object is null?

Comment: Define "obtaining"... You can obviously *obtain* (download) the CSS

Comment: @Amit I think he wants to get it by using some kind of script that gets the DOM, like his example.